# jQuery validation: validating repeat password / two forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am sorry for being new to JavaScript, but this one has been giving me a headache for two days:

I have two forms on my site, and I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin so `input`s can be checked on blur. The plugin validates the email input correctly, but it keeps throwing `success` for passwords that do not match.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
     <form>
           <label for="loginEmail">Email</label>
           <input type="email" id="loginEmail" required />
           <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
           <input type="text" id="loginPassword" required />
           <button>Login</button>
     </form>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
     <form>
          <label for="registerEmail">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="registerEmail" required />
          <label for="registerPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="text" id="registerPassword" required />
          <label for="registerRepeatPassword">Repeat password</label>
          <input type="text" id="registerRepeatPassword" required />
          <button>Register</button>
     </form>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        onfocusout: function(element){
            $(element).valid();
        },
        rules: {
            registerPassword: "required",
            registerRepeatPassword: {
                equalTo: "#registerPassword"
            }
        },
        success: function(label){
            label.addClass("valid").text("OK!")
        }
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Noted.
I've been finding it a really useful thing in SO when people included the correct code in their question.

Comment: You may find it useful, but it doesn't follow the guidelines and can break the site.  The question should remain self-contained and if the code is corrected to include a solution, the posted answers can be rendered obsolete and disconnected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `name` attributes on all of your validated input elements.

The `name` attribute used for the `rules` option as outlined below.  No matter how rules are assigned, this plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of inputs and will not work properly without them.

```
rules: {
    registerPassword: "required",  // <- assigned by NAME attribute
    registerRepeatPassword: {      // <- assigned by NAME attribute
        equalTo: "#registerPassword"
    }
},
```

Just modify your HTML markup as per this example.

```
<input type="email" name="registerEmail" id="registerEmail" />
```

Using the `required` attribute within the HTML is redundant and superfluous **IF** you've already declared the `required` rule within the `.validate()` method.  The jQuery Validate plugin can accept the rule from either case.

Comment: I left the required attribute out of cautiousness, because JavaScript can't make up for what's missing in a markup. I don't think it is really redundant, at that.
However, it doesn't really belong into my question. Editing it out, thank you!

Comment: @emilyTK, you have a `required` attribute along with a `required` rule declared within the `.validate()` method.  The jQuery Validate plugin can use either one, so having both is indeed redundant, and the second occurrence is superfluous.  However, if you remove the `required` attribute and don't also declare the `required` rule within `.validate()`, then the field becomes optional.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it makes sense that way around. Being a JS n00b, I didn't realise the whole damn thing wouldn't break if I removed the `required` rule.